# AngularJS: ngIf in array of array with different properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

my object:

```
objects = [
{
    name: "1",
    foo: [{
      value: 0.5,
      ignored: null,
      text: "foo1"
    }, {
      value: 0,
      ignored: null,
      text: "foo"
    }]
},
{
    name: "2",
    foo: [{
      value: 0,
      ignored: null,
      text: "foo"
    }, {
      value: 0.5,
      ignored: null,
      text: "foo2"
    }]
},
{
    name: "3",
    foo: [{
      value: 0.5,
      ignored: null,
      text: "foo3"
    }]
},
{
    name: "4",
    foo: [{
      value: 0,
      ignored: 1,
      text: "foo4"
    }]
},
{
    name: "5",
    foo: [{
      value: 0,
      ignored: null,
      text: "foo5"
    }]
}]
```

my AngularJs template html:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="object in objects">
  {{ object.name }}
  <div ng-repeat="foo in object.foo">
    <div ng-if="foo.value > 0 || foo.ignored == 1">
      {{ foo.text }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My result is:

```
1 foo1
2 foo2
3 foo3
4 foo4
5
```

but i do not want display `object.name` for case N°5.

How to use 2nd `ng-repeat` and  `ng-if` in 1st `ng-repeat` please?

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-if="...???...">
  {{ object.name }}
  any text !!
</div>
```

Comment: Your array is not an array of arrays but an array of objects. Could you please clarify what you mean by "with different properties"? Does that mean that the elements in `objects` can have different structures?

Comment: @FlorianLim, sorry, I re edit my post

Comment: So why don't you just put `ng-if="object.foo.value > 0 || object.foo.ignored == 1"` on the main `ngRepeat` directive?

Comment: @AlonEitan, foo is an array

Comment: @sgrillon Oh, I didn't see that edit. Can `foo` contain more than one object, or would it always contain a single  object?

Comment: @AlonEitan, no foo array can contain more one object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filter function in `ng-if`.

Changed template:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-if="myFilter(object)">
  {{ object.name }}
  <div ng-repeat="foo in object.foo">
    <div ng-if="foo.value > 0 || foo.ignored == 1">
      {{ foo.text }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Filter function in your controller:

```
$scope.myFilter = function(o) {
  // Returns a truthy value if the foo-subarray meets the criteria.
  var found = o.foo.find(function(fooElement) {
    return fooElement.value > 0 || fooElement.ignored == 1;
  });
  return found;
};
```

Result:

```
1
foo1
2
foo2
3
foo3
4
foo4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="object in objects">
  <div ng-repeat="foo in object.foo">
    <div ng-if="foo.value > 0 || foo.ignored == 1">
      {{ object.name }}
      {{ foo.text }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you know in advance that only one element of object.foo can ever pass the ngIf. (Like is the case in your example)

Comment: sorry but in your solution `object.name` display several times.